# How RAM was allocated in dapp and how to optimize the table?

Tags: smart-contract, ram, ram-allocation, ramcore

We are doing dapp development on EOS. And it seems cost more ram than we evaluated.

How much ram will be used when stored a table record? And how to optimize the table structure to save the ram?

See the example below, how much ram will be used when create a record?
and how to optimize it to save ram?

```
struct producer_info {
  account_name          owner;
  double                total_votes = 0;
  eosio::public_key     producer_key; /// a packed public key object
  bool                  is_active = true;
  std::string           url;
  uint32_t              unpaid_blocks = 0;
  uint64_t              last_claim_time = 0;
  uint16_t              location = 0;


  uint64_t primary_key()const { return owner;                                   }
  double   by_votes()const    { return is_active ? -total_votes : total_votes;  }
  bool     active()const      { return is_active;                               }
  void     deactivate()       { producer_key = public_key(); is_active = false; }

  // explicit serialization macro is not necessary, used here only to improve compilation time
  EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( producer_info, (owner)(total_votes)(producer_key)(is_active)(url)
                    (unpaid_blocks)(last_claim_time)(location) )
```

};

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you calculated your contracts RAM consumption, but the devil lies in the details.

## Index Basics

Using an index is always connected to **sacrify some memory for speed**. This is a well researched database topic. An index is an optimized datastructure with some overhead which organizes data records e.g. in an tree like structure. You can read more about it [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-a-database-index/).

> For [...] example consider the index in the back of a book.  It’s
> pretty simple to use.  Just scan for the subject you’re interested in,
> note, and flip to those pages in your book. [But you will have extra pages.]

Based on your code I guess that you also use **secondary indices which will increase your RAM usage** aswell.

---

## Calculation

So the RAM needed for storing will be:

**number_of_tuples * size_of(struct) + overhead_by_primary_index + overhead_by_secondary_index_0 + ... + overhead_by_secondary_index_n**

---

## Optimization

Looking at your code you could also **evaluate your structs datatypes** and **necessary secondary indices**.

Do you really need a double for total_votes or would an uint16_t (by multiplying by x*10 and cutting the last digits) be enough? Could the last_claim_time also be an uint32_t?

Also is your by_votes() index really necessary? You could also **sort inside the action call**, which will take longer but save RAM.

Like I said the devil lies in the details. Possible pitfalls may also be **working with pointers and references**.