# Tool for tracking BPs performance

Tags: block-producer

Is there any tool tracking BPs performance? Like outages, transactions per block, etc...
If it dose not exist yet - i will make it. And would love to hear what metrics you want to see.

Comment: [This question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/how-ram-was-allocated-in-dapp-and-how-to-optimize-the-table) hinted at someone trying something (possibly/somewhat) similar but I don't know of a finalised service

Comment: another thing that may be interesting to track is how much time they spent as active BPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now some tools for this:

- Made by OP: [EOS BP Stats](https://eosbpstats.com/stats/bp)
- AlohaEOS's [EOS Block Producer Benchmarks](https://www.alohaeos.com/tools/benchmarks) (data from [EOS Mechanics](https://eosmechanics.com/))
- controllinghand's [EOS Value Add Matrix](https://eosratings.com/vam/)
- BlockchainKid's [Mereo](http://www.mereo.io/)
- EOSTitan's [performance tool](https://labs.eostitan.com/#/block-producer-performance) (data from [EOS Mechanics](https://eosmechanics.com/))
- KEOS.io [Top30 Benchmarked BPs](https://keos.io)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there currently are no specific tools for this.

An example of something that could be measured is whether a BP missed a block during the production schedule.

I would recommend that if you were to make such a tool, that you should do so in coordination with the BPs themselves. I imagine they would be supportive of something like this. It would be in their best interests to make sure that such a tool worked as accurately as possible.

Comment: yep, reaching for BPs is part of the plan now. thanx.

Comment: i have some extra ideas on BP performance like avarage number of txs per block and tx time quadratic deviation from median. it should indicate loaded system and swapping potentially.

Comment: can you recommend some way to reach BPs?

Comment: You can see the current list of BPs and their contact details here: http://eosportal.io/chain/12/producers

Answer (score 0):

this is for benchmarking tool for BP cpu
https://www.alohaeos.com/tools/benchmarks